# Could functions be instances of classes in Haskell

Tags: class, function, haskell, types, instance

```
class A a
instance A (Int -> Float)
```

doesn't works and

```
class B b
instance B Int
```

works
If functions in Haskell are taken as the first classes and (Int -> Float)is undoubtly a type although it is not a (*) concrete type, why can't functions be instance of classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With FlexibleInstances extension you can do that:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

module TestFlexibleInstances where

class A a

instance A (Int -> Float)
```

Comment: It really works, and how can I know some problems are due to absence of Language Extension?

Comment: @user1926094 The error message GHC would give for trying an `instance Foo (Int -> Float) where ...` should contain (in not too old GHCs) the suggestion of `FlexibleInstances`.

Comment: I really find the error message contains "Use -XFlexibleInstances if you want to disable this",but I only takes that as an option when compile in shell.Now I realize it is also a language extension

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the function type is not very special in Haskell:

```
module Test where

instance Show (a -> b) where
    show _ = "(function)"
```

As pointed out by shk in his answer, if you want to fix the type of the domain or the range, you will need an extension like FlexibleInstances – but that is not related to the function type and will be required for other type constructor applications like `Maybe Int` as well.